# How to make a unique in R by column A and keep the row with maximum value in column B

Tags: r, unique

I have a data.frame with several columns (17).
Column 2 have several rows with the same value, I want to keep only one of those rows, specifically the one that has the maximum value in column 17.

For example:

```
A    B
'a'  1
'a'  2
'a'  3
'b'  5
'b'  200

Would return
A    B
'a'  3
'b'  200
```

(plus the rest of the columns)

So far I've been using the unique function, but I think it randomly keeps one or keeps just the first one that appears.

** UPDATE **
The real data has 376000 rows. I've tried the data.table and ddply suggestions but they take forever. Any idea which is the most efficient?

Comment: Do a search for `tapply` or `plyr` and you'll find many, many identical questions.

Comment: Regarding the update: You need to give more information. I've tested the data.table solution with 10M rows and 26 groups and performance was satisfactory.

Comment: I was testing the first solution provided. The last update from Roland takes a couple of minutes.
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A solution using package `data.table`:

```
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(A=c('a','a','a','b','b'),B=c(1,2,3,5,200),C=rnorm(5))
library(data.table)

dat <- as.data.table(dat)
dat[,.SD[which.max(B)],by=A]

   A   B         C
1: a   3 0.3631284
2: b 200 0.4042683
```

Comment: But for multiple cols, the result has NAs( Data has only numbers). I want to get max(col1,col2,col3) and by = col3,col4,col5? I tried to expand the same as `dat[,.SD[which.max(col1,col2,col3), by=c(col3,col4,col5)`. But result doesn't look right.  Looking for `select col3,col4,col5,max(col1) as col1,max(col2) as col2,max(col3) as col3 group by col3,col4,col5`

Answer (score 3):

A not so elegant solution using R base functions

```
> ind <- with(dat, tapply(B, A, which.max)) # Using @Roland's data
> mysplit <- split(dat, dat$A)
> do.call(rbind, lapply(1:length(mysplit), function(i) mysplit[[i]][ind[i],]))
  A   B         C
3 a   3 0.3631284
5 b 200 0.4042683
```

Comment: This does a something different than my answer and it is unclear what exactly the OP wants to achieve.

Comment: This solution selects the maximum value for each column, but the OP is asking to select a **complete row** where column 17th has the highest value. @Roland's answer is the only correct one, right now.