# Unique Data Frame Based On Three Column Values

Tags: r

I have a data frame of `6449x743`, in which few rows are repeating twice with same `column_X` and `column_Y` values, but with higher `column_Z` values for second repetition for the same row. I want to keep the row with higher `column_Z` only.

I tried following, but this doesn't get rid of duplicate values and gives me output of `6449x743` only.

```
output <- unique(Data[,c('column_X', 'column_Y', max('column_Z'))])
```

Ideally, the output should be `(6449 - N)x743`, as number of rows will be less, but number of columns will remain same, as `column_X` and `column_Y` will become unique after filtering data based on `column_Z`.

If anyone has suggestions, please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can used not duplicated (`!duplicated`) with option `fromLast = TRUE` on specific columns like this:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,1,2,3,4),b=c(2,2,3,4,5),c=1:5)
df <- df[order(df$c),] #make sure the data is sorted.
  a b c
1 1 2 1
2 1 2 2
3 2 3 3
4 3 4 4
5 4 5 5

df[!duplicated(df$a,fromLast = TRUE) & !duplicated(df$b,fromLast = TRUE),]
  a b c
2 1 2 2
3 2 3 3
4 3 4 4
5 4 5 5
```

Comment: Thanks @PLapointe, but your output removes `c` with higher values. I want to keep the one with higher value. Row `1` in your sample data should be filtered out, not row `2` for what I am trying.

Comment: @ChetanArvindPatil I edited my answer to add `fromLast = TRUE` to `duplicated`. Make sure your data is sorted to keep the maximum data.

Comment: You can using `df[!duplicated(df[,c('a','b')],fromLast = TRUE),]` rather than used`&`

Comment: @Wen That's true.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
library(dplyr)
Data %>% 
  group_by(column_x, column_Y) %>% 
  filter(Z==max(column_Z))
```

It works with the sample data

```
set.seed(13)
df<-data_frame(a=sample(1:4, 50, rep=T), 
              b=sample(1:3, 50, rep=T), 
              x=runif(50), y=rnorm(50)) 
df %>% group_by(a,b) %>% filter(x==max(x))
```

Comment: how about change to `df %>% group_by(a,b) %>% arrange(c)%>%filter(row_number()==n())`

Comment: @Wen Good point. This would return multiple rows in the case of ties.

Comment: Yes, That is my point ~ thank you for sharing the nice solution

Answer (score 0):

Here's an older answer which may be trying to accomplish the same thing that you are:

[How to make a unique in R by column A and keep the row with maximum value in column B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14335733/how-to-make-a-unique-in-r-by-column-a-and-keep-the-row-with-maximum-value-in-col)

Editing with relevant code:

A solution using package data.table:

```
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(A=c('a','a','a','b','b'),B=c(1,2,3,5,200),C=rnorm(5))
library(data.table)

dat <- as.data.table(dat)
dat[,.SD[which.max(B)],by=A]

   A   B         C
1: a   3 0.3631284
2: b 200 0.4042683
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way would be to order the whole thing by column_Z and then remove the duplicates:

```
output <- Data[order(Data$column_Z, decreasing=TRUE),]
output <- output[!duplicated(paste(output$column_X, output$column_Y)),]
```

assuming I understood you correctly.