# R group by key get max value for multiple columns

Tags: r, data.table

I want to do something like this:

[How to make a unique in R by column A and keep the row with maximum value in column B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14335733/how-to-make-a-unique-in-r-by-column-a-and-keep-the-row-with-maximum-value-in-col)

Except my `data.table` has one key column, and multiple value columns. So say I have the following:

```
   a b c
1: 1 1 1
2: 1 2 1
3: 1 2 2
4: 2 1 1
5: 2 2 5
6: 2 3 3
7: 3 1 4
8: 3 2 1
```

If the key is column `a`, I want for each unique `a` to return the row with the maximum `b`, and if there is more than one unique max `b`, get the one with the max `c` and so on for multiple columns. So the result should be:

```
   a b c
1: 1 2 2
2: 2 3 3
3: 3 2 1
```

I'd also like this to be done for an arbitrary number of columns. So if my data.table had 20 columns, I'd want the max function to be applied in order from left to right.

Comment: yeah sorry, I fixed it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I guess there's a dupe somewhere, but `DT[order(b,c), .SD[.N], by=a]` works.

Comment: cool, is there a way to do this generically for any number of columns? This only works if I know what the columns are, and can call them by name. But I'm trying to write a generic function to do this.

Comment: Hm, there's `cols = c("b","c"); setorderv(DT, cols); DT[, .SD[.N], by=a]`, though this actually modifies your data. I wasn't able to find a dupe and my idea (sorting) seems pretty inefficient. Maybe someone else will have an idea. Btw, an alternative to `DT[, .SD[.N], by=a]` is `unique(DT, by="a", fromLast=TRUE)` and you can write `key(DT)` in place of "a" if it's your key column.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a suggested data.table solution. You might want to consider using `data.table::frankv` as follows:

```
DT[, .SD[frankv(.SD, ties.method="first")[.N],], by=a]
```

`frankv` returns the order. Then `[.N]` will take the largest rank. Then `.SD[` subset to that particular row.

Please let me know if it fails for your larger dataset.

Answer (score 1):

to make this work for any number of columns, a possible `dplyr` solution would be to use `arrange_all`

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3), b = c(1,2,2,1,2,3,1,2),
                 c = c(1,1,2,1,5,3,4,1))

df %>% group_by(a) %>% arrange_all() %>% filter(row_number() == n())

# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   a [3]
#       a     b     c
# 1     1     2     2
# 2     2     3     3
# 3     3     2     1
```

Answer (score 0):

The generic solution can be achieved for arbitrary number of column using `mutate_at`. In the below example `c("a","b","c")` are arbitrary columns.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% arrange_at(.vars = vars(c("a","b","c"))) %>%
  mutate(changed = ifelse(a != lead(a), TRUE, FALSE)) %>%
  filter(is.na(changed) | changed ) %>%
  select(-changed)

  a b c
1 1 2 2
2 2 3 3
3 3 2 1
```

Another option could be using `max` and `dplyr` as below. The approach is to first `group_by` on `a` and then filter for `max` value of `b`. The again `group_by` on both `a` and `b` and filter for rows with `max` value of `c`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(a) %>%
  filter(b == max(b)) %>%
  group_by(a, b) %>%
  filter(c == max(c))



# Groups: a, b [3]
#      a     b     c
#  <int> <int> <int>
#1     1     2     2
#2     2     3     3
#3     3     2     1
```

Data

```
df <- read.table(text = "a b c
1: 1 1 1
2: 1 2 1
3: 1 2 2
4: 2 1 1
5: 2 2 5
6: 2 3 3
7: 3 1 4
8: 3 2 1", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dat <- data.frame(a = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3),
                  b = c(1,2,2,1,2,3,1,2),
                  c = c(1,1,2,1,5,3,4,1))

library(sqldf)
sqldf("with d as (select * from 'dat' group by a order by b, c desc) select * from d order by a")

  a b c
1 1 2 2
2 2 3 3
3 3 2 1
```